# Unable to re-size cursor on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gtk, cursor

I have a computer running Ubuntu 14.04 using Unity. I have 3 monitors, 2 externals and a internal. All are 1080p (so the same resolution). I am unable to resize my mouse cursor to be larger. I have tried changing `org.gnome.desktop.interface` (scaling factor and cursor size).

Any clue how to increase the size?

Comment: maybe? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/big-cursor

Comment: @Mateo That only changes it for some applications. For example, it only works in Skype, but not terminal, chrome or sublime text. I guess if it's gtk3, it ignores that.

Comment: So.. What happens when you try setting `org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor size`? Just nothing? I'm guessing you've rebooted after applying the change.

Comment: @Seth nothing. And I rebooted, restarted lightdm, did everything.

Comment: Have exactly the same issue, GNOME Shell 3.14.3, Ubuntu 14.10, linux 3.16.0-34-generic

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what happened this the cursors, but I managed to do partial workaround: find in the web some perfectly scalable cursor theme, then make it default

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme x-cursor-theme /usr/share/icons/path-to-cursor-theme.theme 91
sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

AND make link to the cursors in that folder from default cursors:

```
cd /usr/share/icons/default/
sudo ln -s ../folder-with-cursors/cursors cursors
cd /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/
sudo ln -s ../folder-with-cursors/cursors cursors
```